# How to compute median in an online fashion?

Tags: median, online-algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good algorithm for estimating the median of a huge read-once data set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346/what-is-a-good-algorithm-for-estimating-the-median-of-a-huge-read-once-data-set)

Imagine you have a large, multivariate dataset that resides on disk.

Are there any known methods to efficiently compute median with a minimum number of passes through the data ?

I've found a candidate for variance/stddev in the name of [Welfod/Knutt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#On-line_algorithm), but what about median ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346/what-is-a-good-algorithm-for-estimating-the-median-of-a-huge-read-once-data-set?

Comment: There are several other candidates that should be of interest as well, such as, [Is it possible to accumulate a set of statistics that describes a large number of samples such that I can then produce a boxplot?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3372/1036) and potentially, [Algorithms to compute the running median?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134/1036).

Comment: @ocram : yes, very good entry point for my question, thanks !

Comment: @Andy W, thanks too, those pointers are very good indeed ! Too bad the system didn't manage to find'em when I wrote the question...